# Sorting specific array and print it like tree structure in bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, sorting

I have an array in bash script like

```
# myarr contains main elements (i.e. demo1, demo2) and "sub" elements (i.e. demo1%myspace1::myapp1)
# Inserting element in myarr occurs automatically in that order:

myarr=()
myarr+=("demo1%myspace1::myapp1=param1#param2#param3")
myarr+=("demo1%myspace1::myapp2=param1#param2#param3")
myarr+=("demo1%myspace2::myapp1=param1#param2#param3")
myarr+=("demo1=param1#param2#param3")
myarr+=("demo2%myspace2::myapp1=param1#param2#param3")
myarr+=("demo2%myspace2::myapp2=param1#param2#param3")
myarr+=("demo2%myspace2::myapp3=param1#param2#param3")
myarr+=("demo2=param1#param2#param3")
```

And I want to sort it so that "main" element comes before "sub" elements like:

```
"demo1=param1#param2#param3"
"demo1%myspace1::myapp1=param1#param2#param3"
"demo1%myspace1::myapp2=param1#param2#param3"
"demo1%myspace2::myapp1=param1#param2#param3"
"demo2=param1#param2#param3"
"demo2%myspace2::myapp1=param1#param2#param3"
"demo2%myspace2::myapp2=param1#param2#param3"
"demo2%myspace2::myapp3=param1#param2#param3"
```

After that, I want to print the array like:

```
demo1=param1#param2#param3
 |
 +-- demo1%myspace1::myapp1=param1#param2#param3
 +-- demo1%myspace1::myapp2=param1#param2#param3
 +-- demo1%myspace2::myapp1=param1#param2#param3

demo2=param1#param2#param3
 |
 +-- demo2%myspace2::myapp1=param1#param2#param3 
 +-- demo2%myspace2::myapp2=param1#param2#param3
 +-- demo2%myspace2::myapp3=param1#param2#param3
```

Printing the sorted array is not the problem. Problem is how can I sort the array so that those "main"-elements comes before "sub"-elements?

PS: I use bash 3.2.54 and it doesn't support associative arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to find the main elements from the array, then print each sub-element, sorted.

Here is one way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

myarr=()
myarr+=("demo1%myspace1::myapp1=param1#param2#param3")
myarr+=("demo1%myspace1::myapp2=param1#param2#param3")
myarr+=("demo1%myspace2::myapp1=param1#param2#param3")
myarr+=("demo1=param1#param2#param3")
myarr+=("demo2%myspace2::myapp1=param1#param2#param3")
myarr+=("demo2%myspace2::myapp2=param1#param2#param3")
myarr+=("demo2%myspace2::myapp3=param1#param2#param3")
myarr+=("demo2=param1#param2#param3")

for i in "${myarr[@]}"
do
    # Find main elements
    # A main element is something before a =, that does not include a %
    firstelement="${i%=*}"
    if [[ ! "$firstelement" =~ % ]]
    then
        printf '\n%s\n' "$i"
        printf ' |\n'
        # Print the sub elements related to that main element
        printf -- '%s\n' "${myarr[@]}" | grep -E "${firstelement}%.*::" | sort -n | sed -e 's/^/ +-- /'
    fi
done
```

I defined a main element as an array item that has some text, followed by `=`, and that does not contain an `%` sign.  Ex. `demo1` is a main, `demo1%myspace1` is not.

The `sed` is to add a prefix (`+--`) to each sub-element.

That code produces the output you wanted:

```
demo1=param1#param2#param3
 |
 +-- demo1%myspace1::myapp1=param1#param2#param3
 +-- demo1%myspace1::myapp2=param1#param2#param3
 +-- demo1%myspace2::myapp1=param1#param2#param3

demo2=param1#param2#param3
 |
 +-- demo2%myspace2::myapp1=param1#param2#param3
 +-- demo2%myspace2::myapp2=param1#param2#param3
 +-- demo2%myspace2::myapp3=param1#param2#param3
```

Comment: Thank you. For `firstelement` I use `firstelement="${i%=*}"` without using `cut`.

Comment: Indeed, I have to make parameter expansion a reflex...